# How to start mapping a nested json from a certain index and map it back to that index-1 value

Tags: javascript, react-native

## I want to map my nested json from a certain index

For example if my json is the following:

```
{"data":[{id:1,name:"NAV"},{id:2,name:"Rick"},{id:3,name:"Ceil"}]}
```

I want to start mapping this json from 1st index i.e. id =1 name :rick
and map it till nav so the mapping is in the following order:

1. `{id:2,name:"Rick"}`
2. `{id:3,name:"Ceil"}`
3. `{id:1,name:"NAV"}`

Something like a circular array or queue
I have no idea how to implement this mapping in react native or js.

### How I am currently mapping my json

```
renderArtciles=()=>{

  return this.state.dataSource.map((item,i)=>{
    <Animated.View key={item._id} >
      <View style={styles.Imagebody}>
        <Image source={{ uri:item.img.data }} style{styles.image}/>
      </View>

      <View  style={styles.inner}>
        <ShareItem id={item._id} />
        <View style={styles.inner}>
          <Text style={styles.titleArrtibute}>Trending</Text>
          <Text style={styles.titleText} >{item.title}</Text>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.body}>{item.body}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View >
    </Animated.View>
  });
}
```

Comment: how do you like to stop rendering?

Comment: what i basically want is a something circular so if i have 12345 and i start from 4 it should be something like 45123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with just the `map` function if you find the starting index first.

**Note:** This solution **does not modify** the array.

```js
const { dataSource } = this.state

// set startingIndex using whatever method you have
// to find the index of the first item
const startingIndex = (dataSource.findIndex(item => item.name === 'NAV') + 1) % dataSource.length

// underscore to ignore the current item,
// since we'll index to a different item instead
return dataSource.map((_, index) => {
  const shiftedIndex = (startingIndex + index) % dataSource.length
  const item = dataSource[shiftedIndex]
  return {/* render code */}
})
```

Comment: What if we have no clue that the first item's name is NAV and we just know its index can we still implement this.
If i have to start from 2nd element that is index 1 will this produce the same result?
```const startingIndex = 1% dataSource.length```

Comment: @user3291794 Yes! If you have a method of finding the first item's index, then you can just set the starting index to that number. If you need the next index over, then you need to add 1 to it and do `% dataSource.length`, just to make sure that the increment goes circularly around the array.

Comment: If you know that your `startingIndex` is less than `dataSource.length`, then you don't need `% dataSource.length` for the `startingIndex` calculation. It is still necessary for `shiftedIndex`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick way to pop off the first element from an array and push it to the back.

**Note**: These examples modify the original collection.

If you do not want to modify the original you will need to create a clone of the array first. Or you can go with the "walking the array" approach I've added below.

Overall I do not think you are looking to `map` in this instance, the real question seems to be **sorting** or **iterating** your array in a specific way where it loops.

Once you have *sorted* or *iterated* your array you can then do your *mapping* to extract the data you are after.

### Example - Rotate a Single Element

```js
const cats = ['Bob', 'Willy', 'Mini'];
cats.push(cats.shift());
console.log(cats);
```

### Example - Rotate Multiple Elements

This is if you want to cycle more than 1 element from the front to the back of the array (an example has been attached at the bottom to demonstrate cloning an array).

This will cut off the given amount (2 in this example) and then uses the spread operator to push the new cut off items from the array back into the array. We use the spread operator because splice returns an array and we don't want a jagged semi-multidimensional array.

```js
const cats = ['Bob', 'Willy', 'Mini', 'Dingus'];
cats.push(...cats.splice(0, 2));
console.log(cats);
```

### Example - Nested Data

Since Javascript stores objects by reference we can store variables and apply the same techniques from above to directly modify the original object.

ie: Notice how we assign a new variable `data` and modify it but log the original object `namesInData` which is now changed.

```js
const namesInData = {data:[{name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Willy'}, {name: 'Mini'}]};
const data = namesInData.data;

data.push(data.shift());
console.log(namesInData);
```

### Example - Walking the Array with a For Loop & Offset

We use the modulus operator `%` so that when `i` blows past the end of the array it will wrap back to the front.

```js
const cats = ['Bob', 'Willy', 'Mini', 'Dingus'];
const start = 2;
const length = cats.length;

for(let i = start; i < length + start; i++) {
  console.log(cats[i % length]);
}
```

### Cloning an Array

If you do not want to modify the original array you will need to clone it first.

#### ES6 Way

Using the spread operator we can assign the spread to a new array.

```
const data = [...originalData];
```

### Older Non ES6

```
const data = originalData.slice();
```

### Additional Resources

- [Pop, Push, Shift, and Unshift Array](https://alligator.io/js/push-pop-shift-unshift-array-methods/)
- [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) not to be confused with [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) which does not modify the original array.
- [Cloning an array](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array)

Comment: `[...data.slice(start), ...data.slice(0,start)]` would be my preferred incantation.  Clones array and shifts elements all in one go.  But I'm mostly just commenting so you don't feel ignored. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do it with .map (my instinct is no) but you could do something like the below with a for loop:

```
    let index = 1; //whatever index you want to start from
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        //do all of your stuff referencing data[index] not data[i]
        //at the end of whatever do:
        index === data.length - 1 ? index = 0 : index++;
    }
```

Give it a go, something along these lines should work.

Note: This uses the array index, and not your object id.

Comment: This seems to be what i am looking for, is there no way to do it using map? If not i will do it using for loop thanks.